# How do I create an instance of a inner class in the outer class constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, nested

I switched from C++ to Java and have a problem with nested classes. I would like to initiate an instance of a subclass in the constructor of the superclass. I tried it like this, but it seems to be wrong.

```
public class Aircraft {
    public class LandingGear {
    }

    public Aircraft() {
        Aircraft.LandingGear myLandingGear = this.new LandingGear();
    }
}
```

The idea is that every instance of the class Aircraft has an instance "myLandingGear" of the subclass LandingGear.

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: landing gear *should not **be*** a subclass of Aircraft!

Comment: There is a misconception of what means `has an instance of`. This doesn't need to be an inner class. But Aircraft need to have a variable of this class

Comment: An Aircraft HAS-A LandingGear; an Aircraft is not IS-A LandingGear.  It's composition, not inheritance.  Parents cannot know about children.

Comment: Please note that Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) are for **runnable** in-browser examples using JavaScript, HTML, and/or CSS, not Java. For Java, just use a simple code block (the `{}` toolbar button).

Comment: @AxelH: do you mean as in the answer below by jonhid?

Comment: @duffymo: I did not want to user inheritance, if that is what is done by my example it was by accident. I just wanted to create a nested class... but I am not very firm with the wording in Java.

Comment: In that case it's easy - call new and invoke the constructor.  I would disagree with LandingGear being static.  I'd say every instance of Aircraft ought to have its own.  I don't know what behavior you expect.  I don't see why you've made LandingGear a nested inner class.

Comment: @duffymo, correct concerning the non static nature. And I agree (also thanks to the link postet by T.J. Crowder) that nested class is not the best solution... it was an old habbit of mine. The solution suggested by jonhid works pretty well and is in my understand what you also suggestet. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Aircraft will have a LandingGear

```
public class Aircraft {
    private LandingGear myLandingGear;


    public Aircraft() {
        myLandingGear = new LandingGear();
   }

   public LandingGear getLandingGear() {
       return this.myLandingGear;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, it looks very elegant! Can LandingGear be a class in this case? Is myLandingGear assignable to its Aircraft instance (e.g. myAircraft.myLandingGear)?

Comment: Fabisn, yes... LandingGear should be a independent class with his own attributes/methods... When you create a new instance of Aircraft, this arircrat will have an instance of LandingGear as attribute, to gei it use the getter provided ... myAircraft.getLandingGear()

Answer (score 2):

For this use case, your nested class should be `static` (if it's going to be nested at all), and then you just use a simple `new`:

```
public class Aircraft {
    public static class LandingGear {
    // ----^
    }

    public Aircraft() {
        Aircraft.LandingGear myLandingGear = new LandingGear();
    // --------------------------------------^^^^
    }
}
```

When it's not static, it's an *inner* class, which from your description isn't what you want. [More on nested classes in this Java tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

But unless there's a really good reason for `LandingGear` to be nested inside `Aircraft`, consider making it a peer instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Aircraft {
    public class LandingGear {

        public static void m1()
        {
         //Your code snipet
        }     

    }

    public Aircraft() {
       LandingGear.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.